# Cannot detect intel integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I recently installed a new CPU and need access to its integrated graphics.

I am trying to activate both the integrated and dedicated graphics simultaneously, something my laptop manages.

I've only been successful accessing the Intels integrated graphics if I plug my displayport into the motherboard instead of the AMD GPU. Then my computer fails to find the AMD GPU.

This is when I am plugged into the AMD GPU:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii XT / Grenada XT [Radeon R9 290X/390X]
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hawaii XT / Grenada XT [Radeon R9 290X/390X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:132 memory:4000000000-400fffffff memory:4010000000-40107fffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a0200000-a023ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

It is also missing in `/dev/dri`.

My CPU: Intel i5-10600, with Intel UHD Graphics 630.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the BIOS all along!

With my ASUS BIOS I had to enable iGPU multi-monitor. At first the setting was not present, but after a BIOS update it was available.